# WPF ItemsPanel with Caliburn.Micro MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, itemscontrol

I'm developing a WPF application and using `Caliburn.Micro` for MVVM. I'need to dynamically add buttons into view during the runtime.
I have done some research and I got to know that I can achieve this using an ItemControl.

```
   <Window
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <Grid>  
      <ItemsControl>
      <Button x:Name="ExecuteMethod1" Content="Execute1" />
      <Button x:Name="ExecuteMethod2" Content="Execute2" />
      <Button x:Name="ExecuteMethod3" Content="Execute3" />
      </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </Window>
```

`Caliburn.Micro's` convention allows to call a method which matches to Button's `x:Name` property. In above code button named  ExecuteMethod1 will call a method ExecuteMethod1() in ViewModel.

**Problem:**

As I'm adding buttons dynamically how can I set the X:Name property for buttons?
I tried to set it using `Binding`, but WPF doesn't allow to bind `X:Name` property.
Is there any alternatives? Could anyone can help me with a suggestion?

Comment: You should bind the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of view model items. The view model item class would have two properties, one for the Button's Content, one for its Command. In the ItemsControl's ItemTemplate you would declare a Button, and bind its Content and Command properties to those of the view model item. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens How can I bind commands in CM? Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: I tried this and it worked: `<Button cal:Message.Attach="{Binding TestEvent}" Content="Test" />`

Comment: @Rahul Hi, can you share as to how you were able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this a new feature. Got it working from the Caliburn Micro Documentation.
Add Windows Interactivity Assembly. You can pass to your action the Name or the Content of the Button that shall be enough to identify which button was clicked and perform the right action.
[CaliburnMicro Actions](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn.Micro.HelloParameters.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" />
        <Button Content="Click Me">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SayHello">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=Text}" />
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```